Laravel Tymon/jwt getting correctly information via token
After installing the tymon/jwt package and assigning a token to each user, does the following code, which is related to displaying user information using the token, automatically identify the request and user through the token or not?
auth()->user()

The reason for this question is that I use the following code to generate a token:
$token = auth()->login($user);

And I want to know if Laravel creates a session for this login or not. Therefore, if it does not create a session, it should automatically identify and display user information by reading the information sent by the token on the server side. This issue has confused me a bit.
The codes I have written to implement this scenario are as follows:
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected ?JWTSubject $user = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['signup', 'login', 'refresh_token']]);
    }

    public function signup(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'member_type' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'status' => false,
                    'errors' => $validator->errors()
                ],
                Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
            );
        }

        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request['username'],
            'password' => $request['password'],
        ];
        $message = 'user logged successful';

        $user = User::whereUsername($request->username)->first();
        if ($user) {
            if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(
                    [
                        'message' => 'Username or Password is not correct',
                    ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
                );
            }
        } else {
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $request->username;
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
            $user->save();

            $profile = new Profile();
            $profile->member_type = $request->get('member_type');

            $user->profile()->save($profile);
            $profile->activation_code()->save($activation_code);

            $response = Response::HTTP_CREATED;
            $message = 'user created successful';
        }

        $token = auth()->login($user);
        return $this->respondWithToken($token, $message, $response ?? Response::HTTP_OK);
    }


    public function who_am_i(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        //dd(auth()->user());
        return response()->json(User::with(
            [
                'profile.address',
                'profile.payment_method',
            ]
        )->whereId(JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->id)->first());
    }


    public function refresh_token(): JsonResponse
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh(), 'new token for user created successful', $response ?? Response::HTTP_OK, false);
    }

    protected function respondWithToken($token, $message = '', $status = Response::HTTP_OK, $attach_user_info = true): JsonResponse
    {
        $data = [
            'message' => $message,
            'access_token' => $token,
        ];

        $user = User::with(
            [
                'profile.address',
                'profile.payment_method',
            ]
        )->whereId(auth()->user()->id)->first();

        if ($attach_user_info) {
            $data = array_merge($data, [
                'user'=>$user
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json($data, $status);
    }
}

